# ConcurrentHashMap - adding items with the same Key

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a CuncurrentHasMap:

```
private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object> testParameters =
new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Object>();
```

I am pushing (sometimes) objects with the same keys, those objects are TreeMaps of type TreeMap(string, MyPrivateClass).

How to change this put method, so that objects with same key will be placed together and not be overridden?

```
public static void put(String key, Object object) {

        getTestParameters().put(key, object);
}
```

Comment: `will be placed together` , What do you mean by that? you need to use a map of `<String,Collection<Object>>` for that.

Comment: Maybe you want to use another data structure. You have only one value per key with `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: Do you want some kind of merging of the values?

Comment: What doest `placed together` mean? Do you want to merge the new treeMap with the present one, or do you want to have a reference to both treeMaps? In latter case you should declare your testparameters like a Map of Lists: `ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<Object>> testParameters`, filling the lists in case a key is already present.

Comment: @Selaron : yes, I want to merge the new treeMap with the present one!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As you stated in comments that new `TreeMap` typed values should be **merged** with existing ones, you can rewrite your field and `put` method like this:

```
private static final Map<String, Map<String, MyPrivateClass>> testParameters = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

public static void put(String key, TreeMap<String, MyPrivateClass> value) {
    testParameters.compute(key, (k,v) -> {
            if(null == v) {
                v = Collections.synchronizedMap(new TreeMap<>(value.comparator()));
            }
            v.putAll(value);
            return v;
        }
    );
}
```

The use of ConcurrentHashMap indicates that you are going to access the map concurrently from multiple threads, this is why I added `Collections.synchronizedMap()` as you likely also want to perform reads concurrently on the resulting TreeMaps.

Update: While still maintaining the TreeMaps' entries, I switched from `computeIfAbsent` to `compute` as AndyTurner does in his answer because my former approach was not atomic.

Comment: The first solution is wrong and does not solve for the race condition pointed out by the OP. A `get()` followed by a `put()` is not atomic and so could lead to the exact issue that the OP is trying to avoid. The second solution suffers from the same lack of atomicity and so is also incorrect. @andy-turner's solution is correct.

Comment: @user167019 thank you for your feedback, I dropped the first solution completely and made the second one atomic. After performing computeIfAbscent there was still a race condition in my second solution so that it was unknown which of two or more threads would be the first adding their map entries. Andys' solution is wrong in that it only adds more and more TreeMaps to the List while not merging/updating their entries as asked by the op. Also later reads on that lists may fail during concurrent writes as ArrayList is known to not be thread safe.

Answer (score 7):

Make the value `List<Object>` (or some other container/collection type), instead of `Object`:

```
private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<Object>> testParameters =
    new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
```

and then use `compute` instead of `put` to create and add to the list:

```
getTestParameters().compute(key, (k, v) -> {
  if (v == null) v = new ArrayList<>();
  v.add(object);
  return v;
});
```

Comment: @Oleksandr that's not atomic, so it's not quite the same. You'd have to be adding `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())` to the map for that to work safely.

Comment: @Oleksandr `computeIfAbsent` is atomic; `computeIfAbsent` and `add` isn't. Having executed the `computeIfAbsent` exclusively, two threads can attempt to execute the `add` at the same time.

Comment: I corrected my answer after being notified by @user167019

Answer (score 0):

If this is acceptable to you, you could use an implementation of [Guava `Multimap`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). It can stores multiple values for a single key. Since it looks like you need a Map which is thread-safe, I would use the [Multimaps.synchronizedMultimap method](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/18.0/api/docs/src-html/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#line.416) and do something like this:

```
Multimap<String, Object> multimap = HashMultimap.create();
Multimap synchronizedMultimap = Multimaps.synchronizedMultimap(multimap);
```

Comment: How to import this class to my project?